# subset ls based on position

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of files in a folder that need to be fed piped through to more commands, if I know the position of the files when using `ls -v file_*.nc` is it possible to remove/ignore files based on their position? So if `ls -v file_*.nc` returns 300 files, and I want files 8,73, and 151 removed from the pipe I could do something like `ls -v file_*.nc | {remove 8,73,151} | do other stuff`.
I don't want to delete/move the files, I just don't want them piped through to the next command.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample input of your data and the expected output, so that it would be easier for the people here to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to **filter out** from the input as you said : *is it possible to remove/ignore files*
you can use `grep -v <PATTERN>` which `-v` is an exclusive match option.

input files

```
ls -v1 txt* 
txt
txt-1
txt-2
txt-3
txt-4
txt-5
txt-6
txt-7
txt-8
txt-9
txt-10
```

then ignore any file which contains either 7, 8, 9

```
ls -v txt* | grep -v '[789]'
txt
txt-1
txt-2
txt-3
txt-4
txt-5
txt-6
txt-10
```

removed/ignored

```
txt-7
txt-8
txt-9
```